# Form Application by using HTML

Tags: html

I want to create a HTML form . User will give input and the data will save in excel sheet.

Please support as soon as possible.

Thanks,
Joydeep Karmakar

Comment: What did you try ? Can you update your question with code you have tried?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is here to help with code you wrote but SO is not here to write code for you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. **We are here to help you on your code.** Please read the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) page and take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to find out how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to include Php with this form not HTML only because you should use PhpMyExcel to create that excel sheet and this site will help you to deal with PhpMyExcel functions [PhpMyExcel-Documentation](http://blog.fossasia.org/import-excel-file-data-in-mysql-database-using-php/)

and to create that HTML form you should try this tutorials [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)